# Windows 7 calculator and numeric keypad not functioning properly

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have noticed a problem with my numeric keypad and the use of the Microsoft calculator ever since I installed Windows 7.

When the calculator is started and I want to add two numbers together the typical process would be to yype in 123, press the + key, type in some additional numbers and then press the enter key. This would typically render the summation of two numerics.

Now, in Windows 7, the + key doesn't work. what was being displayed in the calculator when I typed 123 + 123 and hit enter was  123123. I had a buddy of mine in Colorado try the same thing on his computer. He has the same problem.

Does anyone have a workaround for this situation? I should also note my keyboard at home and the office is the Microsoft digital media Pro keyboard and that the only way to get the calculator to work is to use the mouse.

Comment: Try to use both `+` keys, one next to num keypad and one with `=` sign. For me num keypad with Calculator is working fine. Check what kind of keyboard you have setup in the regional settings and if the num Key is turned on. And check if this is not working only with calculator - simultaneously check in the notepad.

Comment: Have you tried all the different modes, such as Basic, Programmer, Statistics etc.?

Comment: Can you describe the behaviour when you actually type the keys? Like [this](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/3323/screenshot15.gif)

Comment: thanks everyone for responding. The problem was resolved this morning. I decided to get a new driver from Microsoft. When I attempted to install the new driver, the installation process indicated the driver was up-to-date.  So I decided to delete the driver and before installing the new one.  I gave the keyboard a whirl and all the function keys.....the plus, the minus, the divide and multiply all were working. So in my case, it was just a malfunctioning driver.  thanks again to everyone